# How do you create an MPTS file on ffmpeg with two h264 inputs?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, h.264

I need to contain two h.264 files (same video, different resolutions) within the same MPTS container, but I can't quite figure out how to use two inputs to create one output.

I tried using `ffmpeg -i (input 1) -i (input 2) (output as an mpegts file)`, but I got an error saying:

`Unable to choose an output format for (output); use a standard extension for the filename or specify the format manually.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The extension name is `.ts`. FWIW, M2TS is not exactly the same thing as MPEG-TS. The former is an extended variant that is pretty much specifically used in Blu-ray, and its extension name is `.m2ts`. Not sure which you want.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think I'm looking for a .ts file. When I try the previous command line prompt with .ts as the extension but that just gave me a copy of the first input. Specifically, I'm trying to play two videos using one container.

Comment: You probably need something like `-i a.meh -i b.meh -map 0 -map 1 out.ts` (with this kind of ordering).